# React Uncaught TypeError when accessing data from axios get request (data is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

Im trying to get data from a collection stored in MongoDB.
When i try to get the data in Insomnia everything works fine. When i make a request with axios i get the following error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'games')

I use a custom Hook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (url) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      setData(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
}, [url]);

const reFetch = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    setData(res.data);
  } catch (err) {
    setError(err);
  }
  setLoading(false);
};

return { data, loading, error, reFetch };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Then i call the useFetch Hook as you can see in the third code block.
When i try to call data[0].games i get the undefined error but when i just call data[0] there is no error and the data is printed in the console.
Here is also the mongoDB model i defined for this case:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const SpielSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    heimName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    heimTore: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    auswName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    auswTore: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});

const TippsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    games: [SpielSchema]
})

export default mongoose.model("Spieltag", TippsSchema)
```

As soon as i want to access any data in data[0]. (number, date, user, userId, games) i get this error.
And here you can see the react code where i call useFetch to get the data. At the moment this is only test code so its hopefully more clear to you :)

```
export const Spieltagtipps = (props) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data, loading, error, reFetch } = useFetch("tipps/find/"+user.username);
  return (
    <>
    {loading ? (
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    ) : (
    <>
     {data && <h1>{console.log(data[0].games)}</h1>}
    </>
    )
    }
    </>
    )
```

Here you can see the two outputs:
[Error when i call data[0].games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgqNz.png)
[No error when i call data[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pLtE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the length of an array as the condition to render as below

```
{data.length > 0 && <h1>data[0].games</h1>}
```

you can check the [falsy values in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

consider rest all which are not in above list as `true` and passes the condition and so `[]` passes too

Comment: WOW, this took me hours! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No worries, feel free to check the [beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/) to learn more :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Im just a week into react and im hyped to get into it more deeply!:)

Comment: follow the link, and you are right on path .... GL